# How to serve create-react-app from Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How can I serve the deliverables of create-react-app via Flask?

After `npm run build`, this is roughly my folder tree:

```
src/
├── service/
│   └── app.py
└── content/
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── many css files...
    │   ├── js
    │   │   └── many js files...
    │   └── media
    │       └── some images...
    ├── index.html
    ├── service-worker.js
    └── manifest.json
```

That's the server's code:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../content', static_folder='../content')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/static/<path:path>')
def static_files(path):
    return flask.send_from_directory('../content/static', path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The main html, `index.html` is served successfully. So are all the files under `content/static/`.

The files under `content/` however (except `index.html`), are not delivered at all (error 404, not found).

Comment: Are you sure the directory listing you gave is correct.  The flask code mentions a `build/` directory but this doesn't appear in the directory listing?

Comment: @v25, thanks, I updated the question (and also double-checked it in my own environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're just trying to serve a bunch of static files, that could probably be done more efficiently with a webserver like `nginx`.

However if you do wish to use Flask, the simplest way to do this with your exisiting directory structure is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='../content')

@app.route('/')
def index_redir():
    # Reached if the user hits example.com/ instead of example.com/index.html
    return render_template('index.html')
```

This essentially serves everything in the `contents/` directory statically at the `/` endpoint (thanks to the `static_url_path` being set to an empty string)

Of course there's also the `index_redir` function which will render `index.html` if the user actually hits `example.com/` instead of `example.com/index.html`.

This also avoids defining the `static_files` function from your code, as flask has the functionality to serve static files out of the box.

Again this stuff is probably better suited to `nginx` in a production env.

Comment: It worked once I added `template_folder='../content'`. Thanks!